# Domain name instead of IP Apache

Tags: apache, dns, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I have a VM running on Ubuntu 14.04 and installed LAMP to host my website virtually. I can, for now, access my website by the IP of my VM through all my network but I would like to access it by typing `mywebsite.com`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you have already purchased a domain name.  If you have not, then you will need to.

Once you have a domain name, you just need to have your domain name point to your IP.  Depending on where you purchased your domain name will depend on how you will do this.  But typically on the companies site in which you purchased your domain name you can find instructions on how to do this through the DNS manager. Here you will be modifying the A records to point to your IP. Once you do this then you will be able to access your server with your domain name.